# How do I assign values to a new category using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a variable, playlists, which I want to assign a categorical variable which takes values of "sleep" or "no_sleep", for each playlist. I have both lists with sleep / no sleep already assign as follows:
Sleep:
"Peaceful piano",
"sleep",
"Baby Sleep Aid",
"White Noise"

No_sleep:
"Dance Hits",
"Dance Classics",
"Massive Dance Hits",
"Dance Party" : ("Spotify", "37i9dQZF1DXaXB8fQg7xif")

How do I add the new variable to the pd.dataframe and assign the values? I imagine an if function for sleep and everything else is No_sleep, but not sure how to get started.

Comment: provide a data sample , and expected output in addition to explanation, check [how to make a good pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is to assign certain entries either `no_sleep` or `sleep` given the playlist name I am guessing.

Here is one way to do this:

```
df['sleep'] = "no_sleep"

sleep_idxs = np.array(df[df['playlist'].isin(sleep_playlists)].index)

df.iloc[sleep_idxs, 'sleep'] = "sleep"
```

Here you would need to have a list of those sleep playlist names (`sleep_playlists`).